# why i cant terminate my process via subprocess terminate?

Tags: python, tkinter, subprocess, global-variables, class-variables

What's wrong with my code?

I can't terminate my proc

```py
class variables:
    var_bhop = IntVar()
    proc_bhop = None

def fbhop():
    if variables.var_bhop.get() == 1:
        variables.proc_bhop = Popen('py BHop.py', cwd='utils', shell= True)
    else:
        variables.proc_bhop.terminate()
```

> I tried all the ways I knew

> But none of them worked

> `Class`, `Global key`, Change statement from `else` to `elif` and second `if`

> And you need to know that I use `Tkinter` for my application GUI

Comment: Try removing `shell=True` option.

Comment: @acw1668 tnx for your help it works correctly but why doesn't work with shell=True?

Comment: From other question on SO, if `shell=True`, the process returned by `Popen()` is the *shell process*, not Python. So terminate the shell process does not terminate the Python process.

Comment: @acw1668 no way to terminate it?